# How to pass arguments to a java code using shell script

Tags: java, shell

I am new to java & shell. I just have a vague idea about the procedure, which is like this-

1. make an executable jar file
2. make a shell script file & include this command in it

   java -jar /home/usr/mystuff/jarFile.jar arg1 arg2 arg3
3. Now the doubts are-

   - There are so many files in my java eclipse project. Do I need to make an executable jar of only the file having main() method?
   - Will the arguments I supply using script be collected by the main function.
   - Whats the syntax of passing arguments in shell. Like $var or var or "var or something else

Comment: Sorry, but this is way to broad. Whole tutorials are written about such things ... so: do some research first. In other words: don't try to use tooling when you have **no clue** what you are doing. That just will not work.

Comment: I guess you are using either maven or gradle, they both have plugins for this, you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: #1 Are you using maven in your eclipse project? #2 What kind of app are developing: desktop, web, api, javafx, sockets? #3 Package to distribute our java applications are fascinating and challenging: detect java on the client machine, download java, icon to launch, etc

Answer (score 2):

To run a jar file in this manner, `java -jar /home/usr/mystuff/jarFile.jar`. You must specify a Manifest file in your jar that has your main class. The manifest file must be placed in a `META-INF` folder in the root of your jar file.

For example, your MANIFEST.MF file should contain a similar entry:

```
Main-Class: com.example.MainClass
```

replace `com.example.MainClass` with the fully qualified name of your Main Class

The entire process listed above will be taken care by your IDE such as Eclipse when you create a "Runnable Jar" from your Java project > Export option > "Runnable Jar".

---

As for passing arguments from the Script to the Jar, you can pass values directly or by using a variable from the script.

For example, directly:

```
java -jar /home/usr/mystuff/jarFile.jar arg1 arg2 arg3
```

OR through shell variables:

```
var1="arg1"
var2="arg2"
var3="arg3"
java -jar /home/usr/mystuff/jarFile.jar $var1 $var2 $var3
```

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1) You will have to be create an executable jar-file, yes (using Ant, Ivy, Maven or whatever)

2) Arguments is collected when you toss stuff to the jar file, jeah
`java -jar <jar-file> "Something goes in here" -DmyCoolVariable=hello`

3) It depends, if you have variables in the script, then pass the variables - if you're using "static" stuff, then just pass the variable directly to the command. Like this:
`java -jar <jar-file> "$variables" -DmyCoolVariable=$someProperty`